# The terminology of 'blockwise' multiplication

Tags: matrices, terminology, block-matrices

Define $v_i\in\mathbb{R}^d$ as a row vector, for $i=1,2,...,n$, and $v\in\mathbb{R}^{nd}$ is a row vector concatenated by $v_i$, i.e.
$$
v = [v_1, v_2, ..., v_n]
$$
Suppose we also have a matrix $M\in\mathbb{R}^{nd\times m}$, concatenated by $n$ matrices $M_i\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times m}$, along the first dimension.

We define a multiplication operator $\odot$ as follow:
$$
v\odot M=[v_1*M_1; v_2*M_2;...;v_n*M_n]
$$
where $*$ is the matric product operator so that $v_i*M_i\in \mathbb{R}^{1\times m}$; $[ ; ; ]$ is concatenate operator (along the first dimension), so that $v\odot M\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$.

My question is that, whether there is a terminology for operator $\odot$? (I guess maybe it should be called something like "block-wise multiplication"?)

Comment: Where does this come up? Seems interesting

Comment: You use both `,` and `;` to denote concatenation. Confusing.

Comment: @Rodrigo: Looking at the sizes of the inputs and outputs, I believe `,` is horizontal concatenation and `;` is vertical concatenation. (This syntax is typically used by Matlab programmers.)

Comment: @Rahul That makes sense. I, too, think in MATLAB-ish ways. However, for me a vector is a column vector by default, which is probably a bad habit.

Answer (score 1):

$$\rm v \odot M := \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm v_1^\top & & \\ & \mathrm v_2^\top & & \\ & & \ddots & \\ & & & \mathrm v_n^\top\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm M_1 \\ \mathrm M_2 \\ \vdots \\ \mathrm M_n \end{bmatrix}$$